# How to set up a lock inside a store procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, locking

I am trying to set up a read/write lock in SQL Server. My stored procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
AS
BEGIN
SELECT VALUE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID=1
UPDATE MYTABLE SET VALUE=VALUE+1 WHERE ID=1
END
```

I would like to be sure tha no-one else is going to read or update the "Value" field while this stored procedure is being executed.
I read lots of posts and I read that in SQL Server should be enough to set up a transaction.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT VALUE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID=1
    UPDATE MYTABLE SET VALUE=VALUE+1 WHERE ID=1
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

But to me this is not enough, since I tried launching two parallel connections, both of them using this stored procedure. With SQL Server Management Studio's debugger, i stopped the first execution inside the transaction, and i observed that the second transaction has been executed!
So i tried to add ISOLATION LEVEL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT VALUE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID=1
UPDATE MYTABLE SET VALUE=VALUE+1 WHERE ID=1
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

but the result is the same.
I also tried to set isolation level in the client code

```
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
    EXEC test
```

but again nothing changed.

My question is: in such situation, which is the correct way to set up a lock that blocks the others?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

> in such situation, which is the correct way to set up a lock that blocks the others?

The correct lock here is to read the table with an UPDLOCK, in a transaction.

```
SELECT VALUE FROM MYTABLE with (UPDLOCK)
WHERE ID=1
```

You can also use an OUTPUT clause to update and return the value in a single query, which will also prevent two sessions from reading and updating the same value

```
update MyTable set value = value+1
output inserted.value
```

However you should *not* generate keys like this.  Only one session can generate a key at a time, and the locking to generate the key is held until the end of the session's current transaction.  Instead use a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or an IDENTITY column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know it's an incorrect design. Unfortunately it's a third party application's design, therefore what I can do is only minimize errors...